# Как получить ответы от WP REST API в utf-8

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Есть ли возможность получить ответ от WP REST API в кодировке utf-8. Простой запрос "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1" вернет, к примеру, вот такой результат в unicode *{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"\u041f\u043e\u0434\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0439 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0448\u0440\u0443\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f URL \u0438 \u043c\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0434\u0430 \u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d","data":{"status":404}}*

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтоб контент возвращался в кодировке utf-8, а не unicode *{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"Подходящий маршрут для URL и метода запроса не найден","data":{"status":404}}*

Comment: Вам API возвращает ответ в json формате, на стороне php просто напишите `$data = json_decode($data, true)` и получите ассоциативный массив с данными.

Comment: Если же нужно ответ обработать на javascript - то можно использовать `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Спасибо, но мне ну нужен ассоциативный массив, мне нужно, чтоб контент в ответе json был в кодировке utf-8, а не utf-16.

Comment: То что вы прикрепили в вопросе - в кодировке unicode.

Comment: Да, простите, unicode...

Comment: Вы же получаете от API объект, вы можете и в php получить этот обьект, без указания второго параметра у `json_decode`, т.е. код будет следующим: `$data = json_decode('{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"\u041f\u043e\u0434\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0439 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0448\u0440\u0443\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f URL \u0438 \u043c\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0434\u0430 \u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d","data":{"status":404}}');`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю зачем вам объект просто парсить как строку, в дальнейшем с ним же будет неудобно работать.

Comment: Мне нужно получить контент записи с моего сайта wordpress для моего андроид приложения. Конечно я могу обрабатывать все полученные данные и переводить контент из unicode в utf-8 в моем приложении, но придется очень много раз использовать эту процедуру, т.к. из приложения можно будет просмотреть записи сайта, страницы сайта, рубрики, метки и т.д. Если бы отправлялся контент в utf-8 мне не пришлось бы каждый раз перекодировать полученные данные из unicode в utf-8. Мне не нужно парсить контент, мне нужно чтоб контент отправлялся в utf-8 а не unicode {"message":"utf-8" }

Comment: Я вас понял, тут два варианта:
1. Править сам wp-json и делать вывод `$data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`
2. Делаете у себя на сайте промежуточный API, где данные сначала конвертируете из JSON, а потом обратно без unicode: `$data = '{ваш JSON}'; $data = json_decode($data); $data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: Фактически флаг `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` говорит о том, что многобайтовые символы не будут кодироваться в unicode.

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный не надо давать вредных советов. во-первых, файл wp-json не существует, править нечего. Во-вторых, править ядро - последнее дело. В-трутьих, в WordPress на всё существуют хуки.

Comment: Вот я это и имею ввиду) Какой хук мне использовать?)

Comment: Я дал вам ответ за 10 минут до того, как вы отправили этот комментарий

Comment: Да, я прочитал ваш ответ, но не ответить на ваш комментарий не смог)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте хук такого вида в functions.php вашей темы

```
add_action( 'rest_pre_echo_response', function( $response, $object, $request ) {
    // проверьте $request, чтобы не править прочие запросы
    // перекодируйте нужные элементы массива $response...
    return $response;
}, 10, 3 );
```